# Trace with TSQLMonitor don't works

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm trying to use the TSQLMonitor component, but I have no success...

I have the follow code in my OnTrace event:

```
procedure TForm1.SQLMonitor1LogTrace(Sender: TObject; TraceInfo: TDBXTraceInfo);
begin
  memo1.Lines.Add(traceinfo.message);
end;
```

Works as well, but "my" values in the SQL command are represented by question symbol ("?"), and I don't no why! Look an example:

```
INTERBASE - isc_start_transaction
INTERBASE - isc_dsql_allocate_statement
**update "CDSUBPRODUTOS"  set
 "DATAINCLUSAO" = ?
where
 "CDSPRCODIGO" = ? and
 "DATAINCLUSAO" = ? and
 "DATAALTERACAO" is null and
 "CODUSUARIOALTERACAO" = ? and
 "CDSPRCODGRUPO" = ? and
 "CDSPRSITUACAO" = ? and
 "CDSPRDESCRICAO" = ? and
 "CDSPRMEDIDA" = ? and
 "CDSPRVALOR" = ? and
 "CDSPRUTILIZARFORMACAOPRECO_SN" = ?**

INTERBASE - isc_dsql_prepare
INTERBASE - isc_dsql_sql_info
INTERBASE - isc_portable_integer
INTERBASE - isc_dsql_describe_bind
INTERBASE - SQLDialect = 3
INTERBASE - isc_dsql_execute
INTERBASE - isc_dsql_free_statement
INTERBASE - isc_dsql_free_statement
INTERBASE - isc_commit_transaction
```

I would likke that these symbols were replaced with the correct values ​​(in this case, the changed values​​). I'm using Delphi XE with Firebird 2.5.

If someone could help me, I'll appreciate!!! Hugs!

Comment: Are you using a parameterized query? If I remember correctly, then you do indeed see the SQL without the parameter values. Don't these come later in the log?

Comment: Thanks Jan Doggen, but I don't use parameters. I made a simple example, just putting a GRID, a NAVIGATOR, a SQLMonitor and a MEMO to get the instruction, and the result is this above...

Comment: See that I did not check correctly the ClientDataSet flags, because was a simple test... =/

Comment: I've posted the simple code at DropBox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/52496155/TestSQLMonitor.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From searching around on the internet it appears that TSQLMonitor does not show the parameter values. There's even a 2002 [Quality Central issue #1358](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=1358) asking for parameter support. I could not find any setting or property either.

Comment: The report is closed as fixed, but if you see resolution comments 'fixed' is in fact inaccurate - it's suggested to use dbxtrace driver instead.

Comment: I don't using parameters, it's a simple query... I have tested with SQLServer, but the result is the same! =( If the SQLMonitor never will return the "values", which is the best way to do this? Do you know?